# PHP's in_array unexpected result

Tags: php, arrays

When I execute this small piece of PHP code:

```
php -r "echo(in_array(0, array('aaa', 'bbb')));"
```

That echoes **true**...

Of course I have the good return value if I add the strict flag to `in_array`, but I just can't understand why it returns **true** (I can't !!).
If anyone can explain me I will sleep well tonight.

PS: Sorry that this is just about curiosity...

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because for `PHP` this code will return `true`

```
0 == 'aaa'
```

So without strict checking `PHP` will find your value in given array.

Comment: That's so weird but you're right. How comes that 0 == false, 0 == 'aaa', but  'aaa' != false ?

Answer (score 1):

Also, check out this code:

```
   var_dump(0 == 'aaa');
   var_dump(0 === 'aaa');
   var_dump(in_array(0, array('aaa', 'bbb')));
   var_dump(in_array(0, array('aaa', 'bbb'), true));
```

The last version allows strict type comparison so it will work as expected, that is return false.

Comment: Yeh I was sure it would never happen to me again but it did (feeling old now ;-)